# PHP Pclzip library: To rename files before being compressed

Tags: php

I am using the [PHP PclZip library](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) to generate dynamic zip archives and the files that are being added to the zip archives have random names.

```
//These are just examples and not part of the actual code
$image = 'random_image_name_ahnfhhsdf.png';
$audio = 'random_audio_name_ahnfhhsdf.mp3';
$pdf = 'random_pdf_name_ahnfhhsdf.mp3';


$archive = new PclZip($zip_folder_path);
$archive->add($image, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
$archive->add($audio, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
$archive->add($pdf, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
```

When these files are added in the archives, they are added with the same names (random_image_name_ahnfhhsdf.png ... etc etc). What I desire to do is give them a consistent naming convention, for eg. tutorial_image.png, tutorial_audio.mp3, and tutorial_document.pdf. Is there a way to do this? Or, in simple words, is there a way I can rename files before the files are added to the archive?

*Please know, I know about the alternate methods to create archives using php (for eg Ziparchive), I am using the library due to code already created using the library.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can `rename()` the file before archiving it. 
eg:

```
`$image = 'random_image_name_ahnfhhsdf.png';
rename($image, 'tpzip\newfile.png')`
```

and after zipping you can delete these new files.

---

I found another solution [here](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/news/3-pclzip-26) for individual files. This works for your problem. But if you have huge amount of file this can slow down the process of archiving. Try this code.

```
$archive = new PclZip("archive.zip");
$new_filename = "new_file_name";
$v_content = file_get_contents( "path to your file" );
$list = $archive->create(
    array(
        array(
            PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_NAME => $new_filename,
            PCLZIP_ATT_FILE_CONTENT => $v_content
        )
    )
);
if ($list == 0) {
  die("ERROR : '".$archive->errorInfo(true)."'");
}else{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: Well, this could be an apt solution but I was looking for something in the _PclZip_ Class that could do this (Ziparchive in PHP does it without much work required). Still, thanks :)